# Multiple Renderactions in View MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have multiple renderactions in a MVC3 view.

I'd like to get a partial View and then the results as the parialviews get in.

(like some placeholders on the page and then the page gets filed up with the renderaction results as the partialviews poor in).

I now have several Html.RenderAction("Action", "controller"); in with different actions on the Main view returning some partial views to be rendered. How do I get them async in return instead of waiting with the render until the last one pops in?

Do I need some ajax or is this done using the AsyncController?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefere to use jQuery ajax. You can simply return PartialView as a ajax action result and then in the jQuery (on the browser side) replace content of specipic part of you page with just returned PartialView.

Quick and easy and no page reload!

Comment: all I get back is "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm" instead of the PartialView as ActionResult that my controller returns.

Comment: Jep, that was my Idea too. I tried @Ajax.ActionLink and that worked gread in replacing a partialview returning as a actionresult, and replacing or appending a <div id ="xy"> tag.  but that is for a link only. I think, there should be a mechanism to to a renderaction like thing with ajax? is ajax.beginform the way to go?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to redirect after calling ajax from jQuery? If yes then you can do that with no problems. Please google for "ajax redirection result".

Comment: I don't think I need redirection. I have a view with multple renderactions. a razor view. these renderactions return a partialview, from a controler, linked to a model. nice and clean. Now, if these models are slow in returning data, I'd like to see page with no data, and then the ajax replaxcing one <div> afteranother with the partialviews coming in from the models via the controllers.

Comment: Each of jQuery ajax calls are asynchrous by the default (you can also use "async": true in the ajax call definition). So wile waiting for the result form the action you can display for example some progrss bar or something like that

Comment: yes, but I now use Html.RenderAction("Action", "controller");  and more than one of them. How do I replace them in an ajax aware async way?

Comment: <div id="xyz">@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName")</div> and then when ajax request will be complete use $("#xyz").html(here_result_of_ajax_request);

Answer (score 1):

Take look a this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { "supporterId": supporterId },
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowDetails")',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#popupDetails").html(result); - here you are replaceing content of you page with partial view returned by the action                   
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

And here is the action:

```
        public ActionResult ShowDetails(int supporterId)
    {
        Supporter supporter = ... //get supporter object from the database
        return PartialView("Details", supporter);
    }
```